# Problems with creating label in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I create simple label in tkinter but it is created with {}, what I don't want to.

```
gameOver=Label(root, text=('Game over!\nYou scored', number, ' points!'),
                               font=('Arial Black', '26'), bg='red')
```

That is my code, where `number` is variable. But it prints "{Game over! You scored} 0 {points!}" 
That is what get with this code (0 is value of `number`)

[image]

Any ideas to solve this problem are welcome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`('Game over!\nYou scored', number, ' points!')` is a tuple of three items, but `text` probably expects a string instead, and does strange things to arguments of other types. Use string concatenation or `format` to provide a single string.

```
gameOver=Label(root, text='Game over!\nYou scored' + str(number) + ' points!',
                           font=('Arial Black', '26'), bg='red')
```

Or

```
gameOver=Label(root, text='Game over!\nYou scored {} points!'.format(number),
                           font=('Arial Black', '26'), bg='red')
```

Comment: I tried first suggestion and it works great. Thanks for help.

Comment: Just FYI, the issue here is not that you passed in a tuple, it's because the strings in that tuple had whitespace.  Tkinter groups the individual strings in this case to indicate which one contains this space.  If you pass in a tuple with no whitepsace, e.g. `text=('few', 'words', 'no', 'spaces')`, Tkinter will automatically populate the label with spaces between each element of the tuple.

Comment: @Jkdc: it's a tiny bit more complicated than that. For example, if your data has a curly brace you'll also get unexpected output.